# How to display data from a nested ICollection within a asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

I am trying to figure out how to bind a nested collection that I have retrieved using EF into either an asp:ListView or asp:Repeater control for a web form.

Using EF I created the following query where I am selecting a group of agencies and a list of the entities they are sharing with other agencies.

```
public static ICollection<Agency> GetAllAgencies()
        {
            ICollection<Agency> retAgencies = null;
            try
            {
                using (var context = new InformSecurityEntities(string.Empty))
                {
                   // retAgencies = context.Agencies.OrderBy(a => a.AgencyName).ToList();
                    retAgencies = (from a in context.Agencies
                                  .Include("SecurityDataShares1")
                                  .OrderBy(a => a.AgencyName)
                                   select a).ToList();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Exception thrown in UserFactory.GetAllAgencies() : " + ex.InnerException + ex.Message); 
            }

            return retAgencies;
        }
```

I've been testing this in a console app and it works fine. Within the console I was rendering my results as follows:

```
private static void showAgencies()
        {
            var results = UserFactory.GetAllAgencies();
            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Id: {0} || Name: {1}",
                    item.AgencyId,
                    item.AgencyName);
                foreach (var i in item.SecurityDataShares1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i.ReceivingAgency.AgencyName); 
                    Console.WriteLine(convertEntityToText(i.EntityId));
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine("enter...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Note: SecurityDataShares1 is an ICollection

What I would like to be able to do is take the results and render them into a format similar to below within a webform:

```
Agency 1
  Entity 1, Entity 2, Entity 3 ...
Agency 2
  Entity 1, Entity 4, Entity 5 ...
```

Where I am getting hung up is in the console app I could access the nested collection and iterate over it to render out my results.  I have tried using a repeater control with a secondary nested repeater and binding the control to the method results.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="agencyListRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="mainRepeaterBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="itemsRow">
                    <div class="column-holder">
                    <asp:Label CssClass="mgmtResultText" ID="lbl_AgencyName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AgencyName") %>' /></div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="mgmtIndentDiv">Sharing data with the following agencies:</div>
                      <asp:Repeater id="nestedDataShare" runat="server">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SecurityDataShares1.AgencyName") %>' />
                      <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SecurityDataShares1.EntityId") %>' />
                      </ItemTemplate>

                      </asp:Repeater>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind

```
   if (userRole.IsSysAdmin)
   {
    var agencyData = UserFactory.GetAllAgencies();

    if (agencyData != null || agencyData.Count > 0)
    {
      agencyListRepeater.DataSource = agencyData;
      agencyListRepeater.DataBind();
    }
   else
   ...
```

However this would fail whenever SecurityDataShares1 was null.

Any suggestions or a best approach for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to get the nested reader to render data, while it would compile, zero (0) results were always returned on the nested objects.  As a result I looked to an alternate solution. *Bear in mind this is more of a work around to the original questionfor rendering the data within the UI*.

Instead of using a data reader I decided to try injecting html directly into the ui using the [LiteralControl class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx). To do this within the aspx page I added a panel control. You could also use a div element with the attribute ruant="server" but I decided to use the `<asp:Panel/>` control:

So within the ASPX file I added the following:

```
       <asp:Panel ID="agencyList" runat="server" />
```

Then within my code behind I created a method with two parameters p = PanelName and a = Collection.

This approach then allowed me to iterate through the collection and write out to the UI the results as html.  *Remember LiteralControl only allows the creation of html elements or strings that do not require serverside processing.* So if you want to add server side controls you will need to use a separate method for the creation of the object [Look here for an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx)

```
protected void CreateHtmlResults(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel p,  ICollection<Agency> a)
    {
        var results = a;
        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            p.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p><b>" + item.AgencyName + "</b></p>"));
            foreach (var i in item.SecurityDataShares1)
            {
                p.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(i.ReceivingAgency.AgencyName + " " + i.EntityId +"<br/>"));
            }
        }
    }
```

This is then called in a format such as:

```
if (userRole.IsSysAdmin)
  {
  //get a list of all agencies
  agencyData = UserFactory.GetAllAgencies();

 if (agencyData != null || agencyData.Count > 0)
 {
   CreateHtmlResults(agencyList, agencyData);                           
 }
 else
 {
    //notify UI that no agencies exist
 }
 }
```

I'd still appreciate any alternative ideas or approaches otherwise I Hope this helps.

-cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In your mainRepeaterBound function you could get a reference to the entity collection of agency.

```
    public void mainRepeaterBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs  e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater nestedDataShare = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("nestedDataShare");
            Agency item = (Agency)e.Item.DataItem;
            nestedDataShare.DataSource = from o in item.SecurityDataShares1 select o;
            nestedDataShare.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

Then your inner repeater would look like:

```
  <asp:Repeater id="nestedDataShare" runat="server">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AgencyName") %>' />
                  <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityId") %>' />
                  </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
```

So now your not accessing a property through an object that might not be there.

Comment: This seems really close something is still missing and it may be due to the EF call. On the inital load of data  GetAllAgencies() I can see data within the SecurityDataShares1 Navigable property. However when referencing the object within the method you suggested above no records exist. The object is not being disposed of it is just returning zero records. (Whereas in the initial query I see 9 results returned.

Answer (score 0):

The Eval statement can be used to set the *DataSouce* property too. The nested repeater would have then Eval statements for the type used in *SecurityDataShares1* list.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="nestedDataShare" 
             runat="server" 
             DataSource='<%# Eval("SecurityDataShares1")'>

     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AgencyName") %>' />
         <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EntityId") %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: The issue I have here is not so much the binding but the data return. With the EF object the nested collection will not be returned if no values exist. As a result the collection could be null or count of zero. Binding the field in the UI as above causes an exception as the properties for the binding cannot be found.

Comment: But you specify Include(SecurityDataShares1), then it should be in memory.